# Creating glossary entries in separate file

Tags: glossaries

Is there any way around to create glossary entries in separate file? I do prefer to store glossary entries in a separate file.

Thanks for any comment.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can store `\newglossaryentry` - definitions in a separate file, say, `foo.tex` and use `\input{foo}` or `\loadglsentries{foo}`

Comment: I have answered your question -- please accept it.

Answer (score 19):

The `\loadglsentries[type]{file name}` command should be used for external definitions, since this allows for selecting specific glossary types (only useful for more than one glossary, however).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\loadglsentries{foo}
\begin{document}

\gls{foobar} is a strange animal

\gls{foo} is another strange animal
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

The `foo.tex` file contains the glossary definitions:

```
\newglossaryentry{foobar}{%
  name={Foobar},
  description={A strange animal, not to be confused with \gls{foo}}
}

\newglossaryentry{foo}{%
  name={Foo},
  description={A strange animal, not to be confused with \gls{foobar}}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why can't one use `\input{fooglossary}`? Thanks.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen: According to the `glossaries` manual you can use `\input` ....

Comment: Why are there 1s at the end of each glossary definition? How does one remove them?

Comment: @Pertinax that is the page number on which the entry first appears. As for how to remove them: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13165/30788

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on `\loadglsentries` with a memoir document class. Instead, create **pages/foo.sty** with your glossary entries:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\usepackage{pages/foo}
\begin{document}

\gls{foobar} is a strange animal

\gls{foo} is another strange animal
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```