# LaTeX Texmaker - Creating a separate file for glossary

Tags: pdftex, glossaries, texmaker

I am currently finalizing my thesis and I am know trying to create a separate file in which I store all the glossary entries. I found exactly the same question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287072/creating-glossary-entries-in-separate-file) but it does not seem to work. I am new to StackExchange and therefore do not feature enough reputation to comment. So thats why I am asking again.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\loadglsentries{begrippen.tex}
\begin{document}

% First part of thesis

\section{example}
Here is an example provided by another stackexchange question, 
\gls{foobar} is a strange animal

\gls{foo} is another strange animal


% Bibliography
\newpage
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{refference}

% Glossary
\newpage
\glsaddall
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

And the other file with the entries: (saved as "begrippen.tex)

```
\newglossaryentry{foobar}{%
  name={Foobar},
  description={A strange animal, not to be confused with \gls{foo}}
}

\newglossaryentry{foo}{%
  name={Foo},
  description={A strange animal, not to be confused with \gls{foobar}}
}
```

When I run the thesis The gls{foo} and gls{foobar} are both shown in the text, but there is no sign of the printed glossary.

Does anyone have any suggetions?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you run `makeglossaries` on your document? You probably need a compilation cycle LaTeX, `makeglossaries`, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX for the full document (here "LaTeX" can be your favourite flavour of LaTeX: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX). If you are using an editor, you hopefully have a button somewhere for `makeglossaries`.

Comment: I am using TexMaker. Could you tell me how to run `makeglossaries`?

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61099/35864 help? (Especially the second answer is interesting: with `\usepackage[automake]{glossaries}` you don't need to run `makeglossaries` yourself. `glossaries` does that for you. Of course that may result in an excessive number of `makeglossaries` runs. So if you are worried about performance, better call `makeglossaries` manually only when required.)

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly! I will add a answer!

Comment: But isn't your question basically a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61099/35864?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @moewe who pointed me in the right direction I solved the problem.

The problem is that glossaries have to be called for. This can be done as descriped in the [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61099/using-texmaker-with-glossaries-on-windows). Just as this question and @moewe suggested it is probably more easy to add a simple specification in the `\usepackage{}` command.

Thus, replace `\usepackage{glossaries}` with `\usepackage[automake]{glossaries}` to solve the problem.